# Change axis to view world from above in Unity

Tags: unity, camera

Developing a 2d game where you view the "table" from above (think of a card game being played on a table).  I have a candlestick on the table, but I must have something wrong because when I run it, it thinks it's on a wall versus a table because the flame goes up to the top versus "at" the camera from above.

[image: How it Looks in Game Mode]
[image: The RedFlame Object Inspector]
[image: The Candlestick Inspector]

Here's the code of that "LookAt" script:

```
public class CameraFacing : MonoBehaviour
{
public Camera cameraToLookAt;
void Awake() {
    cameraToLookAt = Camera.main; }
void Update() 
{
    Vector3 v = cameraToLookAt.transform.position - transform.position;
    v.x = v.z = 0.0f;
    transform.LookAt(cameraToLookAt.transform.position - v); 
}
}
```

Comment: There are lots of ways this flame effect might be set up. Can you show us its inspector and hierarchy setup so we know what we're working with here?

Comment: @DMGregory - Thanks for helping....uploaded the inspectors for the objects which make up this item.

Comment: Looks like the re-orientation is coming from the camera facing script. Can you show us the code for that script?

Comment: Your problem is the `LookAt` script. Somewhere in it it is assuming that `Camera.transform.up` is the "up" direction.

Comment: @DMGregory & Draco18s - Updated the question with that script.  It seems like you're correct.  I think I need to change that transform.LookAt line.